# Theano install warning: g++ not detected

Tags: python, g++, theano

After I installed Theano I tried to run it but got following error message:

```
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected! Theano will be unable to execute 
optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python 
implementations. Performance will be severely degraded.
```

Why?

Comment: Because you don't have the GCC C++ compiler installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the `g++` compiler.

Python is rather slow, so for performance-critical parts you need a compiled language such as C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing mingw (http://www.mingw.org/) as mentioned in the answer posted here - [theano g++ not detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722975/theano-g-not-detected/37846308#37846308)